# Java- JPA @Entity and @Embeddable together

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence, persistent

I'm new to Spring jpa and have a usecase where I need to create:

**Table A** : With Columns 'a' , 'b' and 'c'

And **Table B**  : With Columns 'd' and also columns which are there in **Table A** .

My question is ,

Can I annotate the *POJO* for **Table A** both with *@Entity* and *@Embeddable* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put two annotation by name `@Embeddable` and
`@MappedSuperclass` on above the table A entity and also you will have to inherit table A entity into the table B entity like below.

```
@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
@Entity
class TableA{....}

@Entity
Class TableB extends TableA{...}
```